# A question on star $\sigma$-compact spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

The question is also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376843/a-question-on-star-sigma-compact-spaces).

A topological space $X$ is said to be star $\sigma$-compact if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a $\sigma$-compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

Let $X$  have countable extent and is locally compact. Then must $X^2$ be star $\sigma$-compact?

Thanks for your help.